# How to set focus onto a worksheet of one workbook after visiting another workbook (Excel 365)?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a vba macro that reads data from two workbooks, creates a new sheet in the first workbook, and dumps the processed data into it. The problem is that I can't get the new sheet to show up on the screen after running the macro, instead focus remains onto the last workbook visited. Here's an MWE:

```
Const PROC_NAME = "LIST DIFFERENCES"
Const ERR_USR_CANCEL = 111

Dim wbOne As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, rg As Range

Sub ListDif()
  Dim shDataMix As Worksheet
  
  On Error GoTo EH:
  
  DataRead
 
  Set shDataMix = wbOne.Sheets.Add(before:=ws1)
  
  With shDataMix
    .Cells(1, 1) = "Something"
  End With
  
EH:
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Select Case Err.Number
      Case ERR_USR_CANCEL
        MsgBox "Canceled by user", vbExclamation, PROC_NAME
      Case Else
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, PROC_NAME
    End Select
  Else
    wbOne.Activate
  End If
  
  Set rg = Nothing
  Set wbOne = Nothing
  Set ws1 = Nothing
  Set shDataMix = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub DataRead()
  Set wbOne = ActiveWorkbook
  Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
  With ws1
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rg = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the FIRST data range", _
      Title:=PROC_NAME, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rg Is Nothing Then
      Err.Raise ERR_USR_CANCEL
    Else
      With rg
        Debug.Print .Rows.Count
      End With
    End If
  End With
    
  Set rg = Nothing
  On Error Resume Next
    Set rg = Application.InputBox("Select the SECOND data range", _
        PROC_NAME, Type:=8)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If rg Is Nothing Then
    Err.Raise ERR_USR_CANCEL
  Else
    With rg
      Debug.Print .Rows.Count
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

It is puzzling that if I run the macro step by step, it does what I want. Is it possible that this is a "bug" in the version of Excel that I am using?
(Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (version 2110 build 16.0.14527.20234) 64-bit)

Comment: `wbOne.Activate`, `shDataMix.Activate`.

Comment: @BigBen: Thanks for your prompt reply! Unfortunately, the same thing happens: if I run the macro step by step, it works, but directly, it does not. I've tried every combination of "Activates" and "Selects" I could think of, but none of them work :(

You may have already noticed that English is not my native language. Faced with grammatical or spelling errors, the fault lies with Google's translator.

Comment: You probably should also add `Exit Sub` before `EH:`

Comment: @BigBen: I reiterate my thanks. Nothing changes by putting "exit sub" before EH - an obvious solution would be to swap the order in which the workbooks are visited, but it does alter the logic the macro was created with (and besides, it's annoying not being able to do this task, seemingly trivial).

Comment: When you are running the macro step-by-step you are probably in the correct sheet and workbook for ActiveWorkbook and ActiveSheet.  When you running outside of that you may be referencing other sheets/workbooks.  Best to be specific.

Comment: @Darrell h and BigBen: Thanks for your time! The macro resides in the Excel Personal macro workbook and the initially active workbook will always be the one in which the new sheet is created. As far as I understand, that does not appear to be the source of the problem. Can anyone run my MWE in their version of Excel and check if the problem persists in that version? At this point, it's just curiousity ...